# HttpContext.RequestAborted not signalling when services are load-balanced using azure application gateway

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-gateway

We have asp.net core api, that is hosted in docker in azure vm's. And the api is load balanced using azure application gateway.

We are using HttpContext.RequestAborted to cancel any long running processes when the client request is aborted or give-up. It's working when we run the api locally in Visual Studio. But not when it's deployed in to a load balanced environment.  We believe it's due to the application gateway not forwarding the cancellations. Is our assumptions correct or anything we need to configure in api/app-gatway to get it working ?

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.